# xml record Ir.rule AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have an error with this record definition

```
<record id="file_rule_canceled" model="ir.rule">
    <filed name="name"> File Canceled=True  User Cann't Read</filed>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_muk_dms_file"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('canceled','=','True')] </field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_gesion_dms_general_manager')), (4, ref('group_gesion_dms_manager')),(4, ref('group_gesion_dms_designer')),(4,ref('group_gesion_dms_reader'))]"/>
</record>
```

Odoo Server Error:

```
  File "D:\Odoo10_Dev\odoo10\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 902, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3501, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:194922)
AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: record, line 4
```

Could you help to find out what it's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<record id="file_rule_canceled" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">File Canceled=True User Can't Read</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_muk_dms_file"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('canceled','=','True')]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_gesion_dms_general_manager')), (4, ref('group_gesion_dms_manager')),(4, ref('group_gesion_dms_designer')),(4,ref('group_gesion_dms_reader'))]"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Would be nice to find out what was wrong ;-) For example that typo `filed` which should have been `field`. Please add something into your answer, it will help to understand it better.